# Changing CSS styles when an event fires

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to integrate `THEOPlayer` in my project and I want to customize styles depending on certain events. For instance, I would love to hide the toolbar and show an overlay image when the video is paused.
They do expose some CSS classes that I can change manually but my question is, how do I change the values in CSS on a specific event.  Since the player is imported as a single JSX element I don't know how to add custom classes to its specific parts. So I would like to know if there is another way.

Here is a component where an instance of Player is created:

```
class Player extends React.Component {
  _player = null;
  _el = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const { source, onPlay, onPause } = this.props;

    if (this._el.current) {
      this._player = new window.THEOplayer.Player(this._el.current, {
        libraryLocation:
          "https://cdn.myth.theoplayer.com/7aff3fa6-f92e-45f9-a40e-1bce9911b073/",
      });

      this._player.source = source;
      this._player.addEventListener("play", onPlay);
      this._player.addEventListener("pause", onPause);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this._player) {
      this._player.destroy();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={
          "theoplayer-container video-js theoplayer-skin vjs-16-9 THEOplayer"
        }
        ref={this._el}
      >
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Player;
```

And that's a part of code where I want to change styles `onPlay` and `onPause`

```
      <div className={"player-container"}>
        <Player
          source={source}
          onPlay={() => {
            console.log("playing");
          }}
          onPause={() => {
            console.log("paused");
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
state = {
  play: false,
  pause: true,
}
const playFn = () => {
  this.setState = ({
    play: true,
    pause: false,
  })
}
const pauseFn = () => {
  this.setState = ({
    play: false,
    pause: true,
  })
}
 <div className={"player-container"}>
        <Player
          source={source}
          onPlay={playFn}
          onPause={pauseFn}
          activatePlayClasses={play}
          activatePauseClasses={pause}
          bg={'https://example/example.jpg'}
        />
</div>

// on Player component
const { source, onPlay, onPause, activatePauseClasses, activatePlayClasses , bg} = this.props;


render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={
          `theoplayer-container video-js theoplayer-skin vjs-16-9 THEOplayer 
           ${activatePauseClasses ? 'your pause class' : ''}
           ${activatePlayClasses ? 'your play class' : ''}`
        }
        style={{backgroundImage: `url(${bg})`}}
        ref={this._el}
      >
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I have updated code

Comment: Ok. I get that, what I'm struggling with is that I need to target classes that are not exposed in the React code. For instance, if I want to set up a background picture for the player when it's paused I need to target  .theoplayer-skin.vjs-paused .theo-player-wrapper:before class in my CSS file. The question is, what if I want to set up background pics dynamically from ```props```, how do I pass the url to CSS file or if that's not possible, what are the other options?

Comment: In that case, it would add the background image to  theoplayer-container video-js theoplayer-skin vjs-16-9 THEOplayer' class. 
I need that picture to be attached to the class  .theoplayer-skin.vjs-paused .theo-player-wrapper:before which is not exposed in JSX, it only exists on the instance of the player

Comment: no issue with that. Add your custom class and  overwrite that css with your css. if necessary use important